# Rails getting error when creating new rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I am trying to create new rails application using **rails new app_name**  It is giving me error .

```
Warning: You're using Rubygems 1.8.23 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.
Type 'rails' for help.
```

I look on internet and read few solutions on stack overflow but wasn't helpful .I even tried gem pristine --all but it didn't work either

when i run **rvm list** on terminal

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.2.1'.

rvm rubies

   ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]

# Default ruby not set. Try 'rvm alias create default <ruby>'.

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

when i run **rvm** on terminal

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.2.1'.
= rvm

* https://rvm.io/
* https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/

== DESCRIPTION:

RVM is the Ruby enVironment Manager (rvm).

It manages Ruby application environments and enables switching between them.

== Installation

  curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=enabled [--ruby] [--rails] [--trace]

stable     :: Install stable RVM, good for servers.
--ruby     :: Additionally install latest ruby version (MRI).
--rails    :: Install gem rails into default gemset (also installs ruby=).
--trace    :: Print trace of the installation, gist output when you have problems.
--autolibs :: Enable or disable autolibs see: https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs

More details here: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

== Usage

  rvm [Flags] [Options] Action [Implementation[,Implementation[,...]]

== Flags

--default         :: with 'rvm use X', sets the default ruby for new shells to X.
--debug           :: Toggle debug mode on for very verbose output.
--disable-binary  :: Install from source instead of using binaries
--trace           :: Toggle trace mode on to see EVERYTHING rvm is doing.
--force           :: Force install, removes old install & source before install.
--summary         :: Used with rubydo to print out a summary of the commands run.
--latest          :: with gemset --dump skips version strings for latest gem.
--gems            :: with uninstall/remove removes gems with the interpreter.
--docs            :: with install, attempt to generate ri after installation.
--reconfigure     :: Force ./configure on install even if Makefile already exists.
--skip-gemsets    :: with install, skip the installation of default gemsets.
--quiet-curl      :: Makes curl silent when fetching data

== Options

-v|--version     :: Emit rvm version loaded for current shell
-l|--level       :: patch level to use with rvm use / install
   --bin         :: path for binaries to be placed (~/.rvm/bin/)
-S               :: Specify a script file to attempt to load and run (rubydo)
-e               :: Execute code from the command line.
--gems           :: Used to set the 'gems_flag', use with 'remove' to remove
                    gems
--archive        :: Used to set the 'archive_flag', use with 'remove' to remove
                    archive
--patch          :: With MRI Rubies you may specify one or more full paths to
                    patches

                    for multiple, specify comma separated:

                      --patch /.../.../a.patch[%prefix],/.../.../.../b.patch

                    'prefix' is an optional argument, which will be bypassed
                    to the '-p' argument of the 'patch' command. It is separated
                    from patch file name with '%' symbol.
-C|--configure   :: custom configure options. If you need to pass several
                    configure options then append them comma separated:

                      -C --...,--...,--...

--nice           :: process niceness (for slow computers, default 0)
--ree-options    :: Options passed directly to ree's './installer' on the
                    command line.
--with-rubies    :: Specifies a string for rvm to attempt to expand for set
                    operations.

== Action

(Note: for most actions, 'rvm help action-name' may provide more information.)

*usage*     :: show this usage information
version     :: show the rvm version installed in rvm_path
use         :: setup current shell to use a specific ruby version
reload      :: reload rvm source itself (useful after changing rvm source)
implode     :: (seppuku) removes the rvm installation completely.

               This means everything in $rvm_path (~/.rvm || /usr/local/rvm).

               This does not touch your profiles. However, this means that you
               must manually clean up your profiles and remove the lines which
               source RVM.
get         :: {head,stable} upgrades rvm to latest head or stable version.

               Check 'rvm help get' for more details.

               (If you experience bugs try this first with head version, then
               ask for help in #rvm on irc.freenode.net and hang around)
reset       :: remove current and stored default & system settings.

               (If you experience odd behavior try this second)
info        :: show the *current* environment information for current ruby
current     :: print the *current* ruby version and the name of any gemset
               being used.
debug       :: show info plus additional information for common issues

install     :: install one or many ruby versions

               See also: https://rvm.io/rubies/installing/
uninstall   :: uninstall one or many ruby versions, leaves their sources
remove      :: uninstall one or many ruby versions and remove their sources
reinstall   :: reinstall ruby and runs gem pristine on all gems,
               make sure to read output, use 'all' for all rubies.

migrate     :: Lets you migrate all gemsets from one ruby to another.
upgrade     :: Lets you upgrade from one version of a ruby to another, including
               migrating your gemsets semi-automatically.

wrapper     :: generates a set of wrapper executables for a given ruby with the
               specified ruby and gemset combination. Used under the hood for
               passenger support and the like.

cleanup     :: Lets you remove stale source folders / archives and other
               miscellaneous data associated with rvm.
repair      :: Lets you repair parts of your environment e.g. wrappers, env
               files and and similar files (e.g. general maintenance).
fix-permissions :: Repairs broken permissions (e.g. by sudo or chef)
osx-ssl-certs :: Helps update certificates for OpenSSL installed by rvm on OSX.
snapshot    :: Lets you backup / restore an rvm installation in a lightweight
               manner.

alias       :: Lets you set shortcut strings for convenience with 'rvm use'.
disk-usage  :: Tells you how much disk space rvm install is using.
tools       :: Provides general information about the ruby environment,
               primarily useful when scripting rvm.
docs        :: Tools to make installing ri and rdoc documentation easier.
rvmrc       :: Tools related to managing rvmrc trust and loading.
patchset    :: Tools related to managing ruby patchsets.

do          :: runs an arbitrary command against specified and/or all rubies
cron        :: Manages setup for using ruby in cron tasks.

gemset      :: gemsets: https://rvm.io/gemsets/

rubygems    :: Switches the installed version of rubygems for the current ruby.

config-get  :: display values for RbConfig::CONFIG variables.
gemdir      :: display the path to the current gem directory (GEM_HOME).


fetch       :: Performs an archive / src fetch only of the selected ruby.
list        :: show currently installed rubies, interactive output.

               https://rvm.io/rubies/list/
autolibs    :: Controls settings for automatically installing dependencies.
pkg         :: Install a dependency package {readline,iconv,zlib,openssl}

               https://rvm.io/packages/
notes       :: Display notes, with operating system specifics.

export      :: Temporarily set an environment variable in the current shell.
unexport    :: Undo changes made to the environment by 'rvm export'.
requirements  :: Installs additional OS specific dependencies/requirements for
                 building various rubies. Usually run by install.
mount       :: Install rubies from external locations.

user        :: Tools for managing RVM mixed mode in multiuser installations.
group       :: Tools for managing groups in multiuser installations.

== Implementation

*ruby*     :: MRI/YARV Ruby (The Gold Standard) {1.8.x, 1.9.x, 2.0.x, 2.1.x, 2.2.x}
jruby      :: JRuby, Ruby interpreter on the Java Virtual Machine.
rbx        :: Rubinius
ree        :: Ruby Enterprise Edition, MRI Ruby with several custom
              patches for performance, stability, and memory.
macruby    :: MacRuby, insanely fast, can make real apps (Mac OS X Only).
maglev     :: GemStone Ruby, awesome persistent ruby object store.
ironruby   :: IronRuby, NOT supported yet. Looking for volunteers to help.
system     :: use the system ruby (eg. pre-rvm state)
default    :: use the default ruby (or the system ruby if a default hasn't been set).

              https://rvm.io/rubies/default/

== Resources:

https://rvm.io/
https://www.pivotaltracker.com/projects/26822

== Contributions:

Any and all contributions offered in any form, past present or future, to the
RVM project are understood to be in complete agreement and acceptance with the
Apache License v2.0.

== LICENSE:

Copyright (c) 2009-2011 Wayne E. Seguin
Copyright (c) 2011-2015 Michal Papis

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.

  Action documentation available with 'rvm help action-name':

      alias autolibs cleanup config-get cron current debug disk-usage do docs fetch fix-permissions gemdir gemset gemset/copy get group implode info install list migrate mount notes osx-ssl-certs patchset pkg prepare reinstall remove repair requirements reset rubygems rvmrc rvmrc/to rvmrc/warning snapshot srcdir tools uninstall upgrade use user wrapper 

  Other topics of documentation available with 'rvm help topic':

      alt color upgrade-notes 


  For additional information please visit RVM's documentation website:

      https://rvm.io/

  If you still cannot find an answer to your question, find
  'wayneeseguin', 'mpapis', 'richo', 'lemoinem' or 'rys' in #rvm on irc.freenode.net:

      http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm
```

Comment: Did you read the second line? Did you follow *that* advice?

Comment: yeah I have follow the advice .Firstly I have created a new directory  and then i run the command rails new app_name but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that you're already in a existing rails application.

So either:

1. this is true, and you're doing something that isn't supported; or
2. this is false, and this error is wrong.

Lets look at the code that shows this error.

By using:

```
$ grep -r 'initialize a new Rails application within the directory' ~/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/
```

I found that this error is shown in:

```
/home/martin/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:        puts "Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.\n"
```

By opening that file I found that this is in the function `exit_with_initialization_warning!`, which is called just once:

```
def new
  if %w(-h --help).include?(argv.first)
    require_command!("application")
  else
    exit_with_initialization_warning!
  end
end
```

So how does this work? When you type `rails` it loads up `/home/martin/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/bin/rails`, which does `require "rails/cli"`, which looks like:

```
require 'rails/app_rails_loader'

# If we are inside a Rails application this method performs an exec and thus
# the rest of this script is not run.
Rails::AppRailsLoader.exec_app_rails

require 'rails/ruby_version_check'
Signal.trap("INT") { puts; exit(1) }

if ARGV.first == 'plugin'
  ARGV.shift
  require 'rails/commands/plugin'
else
  require 'rails/commands/application'
end
```

The logic to find if this is a rails directory is:

```
def exec_app_rails
  original_cwd = Dir.pwd

  loop do
    if exe = find_executable
      contents = File.read(exe)

      if contents =~ /(APP|ENGINE)_PATH/
        exec RUBY, exe, *ARGV
        break # non reachable, hack to be able to stub exec in the test suite
      elsif exe.end_with?('bin/rails') && contents.include?('This file was generated by Bundler')
        $stderr.puts(BUNDLER_WARNING)
        Object.const_set(:APP_PATH, File.expand_path('config/application', Dir.pwd))
        require File.expand_path('../boot', APP_PATH)
        require 'rails/commands'
        break
      end
    end

    # If we exhaust the search there is no executable, this could be a
    # call to generate a new application, so restore the original cwd.
    Dir.chdir(original_cwd) and return if Pathname.new(Dir.pwd).root?

    # Otherwise keep moving upwards in search of an executable.
    Dir.chdir('..')
  end
end
```

This seems pretty fool-proof to me, and can't be "fooled" with just the existence of a `bin/rails` in some parent directory; it also looks at the contents, and actually *runs* the file (which would require various dependencies and would most likely error out unless you're in a rails directory).

We see that `require 'rails/commands'` is called *only* when we're running inside a rails directory, so this is why the `new` function always throws an error (the `%w(-h --help).include?(argv.first)` is there to allow running `rails new -h` from inside rails apps).

When you're outside a rails directory, the `new` command in implemented in `commands/application.rb`, which is called from `cli.rb` (which runs `Rails::Generators::AppGenerator.start`).

**Conclusion**: You're almost certainly creating a rails application inside a rails application. Don't do this.

Comment: sir I am not creating a rails application inside another application .I am using ubuntu as my os .Firstly I am creating directory using mkdir folder_name .And then i type cd folder_name.After that rails new app-name

Comment: and i get the error do i need to update something.I am a rails developer its more than 5 months I am working on it .And I have tried this 100 times.And that mistake is done by newbie or who are new to rails

Comment: @aniket Then I don't know what is going on. I have given you the explanation of what `rails new` does and how it works; you should now have the tools to solve your own problem by tracing the code and seeing what goes wrong. I do not have access to your system, and can't do this for you. The simplest way to do so is so-called "printf-debugging" (i.e. placing some strategic `put` statements to inspect the state of the program ...

Comment: can i tell you my problem complete

Comment: When i run any of my other rails application it works. When I look for the rails and ruby version they are also up to date ..but when i create a new directory and then try to create rails application it show me the error which I have mention above.when i try to look for the ruby version over there it shows me an outdated version of ruby ..So how come this is possible ??Also when I run rvm list

Comment: I am updating my question

Comment: @aniket Are you *really, really, really* sure there isn't a Rails app in a parent directory? Because the outdated Rails and Ruby version is consistent with a `Gemfile` specifying a specific ruby and rails version... You say you "created a directory", but that doesn't mean anything. If you once (perhaps accidentally) created a rails app in `~/code/2016` and are now trying to create a rails app in `~/code/2016/february/new_app` you will get this error. Maybe you even did something like `rails new ~` once by accident?

Comment: updated ..sir if you can help me it will be very grateful

Comment: Sir I am 100% sure I am creating rails application in different folder .Sir should i show you screenshot what I am doing ....And sir I don't know whether I have done rails new ~ or not?

Comment: Well, a "screenshot" would not provide the contents of the current directory and *all* parent directories, would it? Like I suggested a few comments ago, do some printf-debugging in the code that's in my answer. This will be the fastest way to get your solution...

Comment: @aniket I saw you marked this as correct. May I ask what the problem ended up being? I am curious and would like to know :-) Many thanks!

Comment: sir actually i deleted all the things from my system and install first rvm ,then ruby after that rails..and then i was able to solve my prb.I marked ur answer correct because the information was very helpful specially i came to know how actually rails application starts

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
Update the bundler gem using

```
gem update bundler
```

Full answer:
Rubies recently published were shipped with bundler v2.3.7 which contains a known issue (rubygems/rubygems#5386) for autoloading Gem::Source.

Now since it has been reproduced and solved, an update of the bundler gem (up to v2.3.9 or newer version) could simply fix it.

Source of the informtion:
https://blog.aidistan.site/2022/08/23/how-to-fix-rails-initialization.html

PS: I'm not aware why my previous post was deleted, as this solution helped me well to solve the problem and also could help others. Maybe two lines were not enough, so I write more this time.

Comment: Your original answer was deleted (by a moderator) for being "link-only". You can't undelete it (only a mod can do that). What you can do is flag your first (now edited) answer as "In need of moderator action" and explain that you have edited in more details. But you should probably delete this second post, beforehand.